# Read data from a specific row and column and write into a different row and different column using POI and Java

Tags: java, excel, loops, multidimensional-array, apache-poi

reading excel file from this format.

```
RA1 RB1 RC1   IP D1 IP E1   IP F1
RA2 RB2 RC2   IP D2 IP E2   IP F2
RA3 RB3 RC3   IP D3 IP E3   IP F3
```

Need to write excel in to this formate

```
RA1 RB1 RC1 IP D1       
RA1 RB1 RC1 IP E1       
RA1 RB1 RC1 IP F1       

RA2 RB2 RC2 IP D2       
RA2 RB2 RC2 IP E2       
RA2 RB2 RC2 IP E3       

RA3 RB3 RC3 IP F1       
RA3 RB3 RC3 IP F2       
RA3 RB3 RC3 IP F3
```

Is there any way so I can do it without saving values in array. Following is my loop but not getting it in required format.

```
//loop to read data and store in array

            for ( i = 0; i <=Lastrow; i++)
            { 

                for ( j = 0; j <=R_endColumn; j++)
                {

                Row readrow= sheet.getRow(i);
                Cell readcell=readrow.getCell(j);
                String datavalues = df.formatCellValue(readcell);
                System.out.println(datavalues);
                localstore[i][j]= datavalues;
                }
            }

            int newrow_Number=0;
                // Loop to write data in seprate excel file in

            for ( i = 0; i <=Lastrow; i++)
            { 

                for ( int k = 0; k <=Lengthof_IP; k++) 
                { 
                newrow_Number=newrow_Number+1;
                for ( j = 0; j <=requirement_endColumn; j++)
                {

                Row readrow=sheet.createRow(newrow_Number);
                Cell readcell=readrow.getCell(j, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                String datavalues = df.formatCellValue(readcell);
                readcell.setCellValue(localstore[i][j]);
                }

            }   
            }

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/DataTransformation/op1.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
```

Comment: What's your problem if you don't use array?

Comment: Not able to use correct loop. Data is not writing in required format.